# Opera waits indefinitely for certain pages

Tags: networking, browser, opera, wait

I have a very strange problem, that from time to time Opera stops opening certain pages. It hangs forever on "*Waiting for XXX...*" message. The strangest part is, that sometimes problem covers not only whole domains, but also subdomains. For example:

- I can open Facebook, but can't any page within Stack Exchange network.
- I can open Gmail and Google Calendar, but opera hangs on Google Maps or Google Translate.

What I managed to figure so far:

1. Problem is narrowed to Opera browser only, and is in nowhere related to my computer or network. When Opera hangs on "*Waiting for XXX...*" message, I can open the very same page, in the very same time in either Firefox, IE or Chrome. My wife, using different computer, but connected to the same network, hasn't got any problems, though she is not using Opera.
2. I haven't observed anything like that in Opera installed on my office computer (different network).
3. Problem appears suddenly, without any specific actions taken from my side. For example, I was opening all pages, without any problems three hours ago, then shut down my computer, turned it on again after few hours and now I can't open certain pages in Opera only.
4. Restarting Opera or entire system brings no effect. Only purging all cookies solves the problem.

The only anti-malware software, that I have installed and running is *Microsoft Security Essentials*. However, I don't think, it can cause these problems, since they're narrowed to Opera browser only. Other browsers and other computers in my network seems to be not affected by this problem.

**Since this is quite annoying** (happens out of nowhere and forces me to clear cookies, so I end up being logged off from everything I was using), **I'd like to ask, if someone got any idea, what can be happening or how to solve or work around this problem?**

*I have Opera 33.0 (`33.0.1990.115`) -- newest and up to date so far. I'm using Windows 7 on all my computers (including home, where problem appears, and office one, where it seems to be gone).*

Comment: Have you tried a new opera profile?

Comment: @LPChip Nope, that slipped my mind! Thanks, I'll do some testings.